# ffmpeg with mp3 support: How to install (use) in user mode?

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg and libmp3lame on a stable Debian box. Alas, Debian does not support the libmp3lame package. So, I downloaded the sources for ffmpeg and the lame encoder, configured and installed them manually (on a testing machine).

But I do not want to install ffmpeg and libmp3lame on the machine for all users (also because the built is not stable). I only want to use it for a single project with a single user.

When I run ./ffmpeg/ffmpeg I get following error message:

```
# cd ffmpeg
# ./configure --enable-libmp3lame
# make
# ./ffmpeg
./ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libmp3lame.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

So I simply tried to link the required library to the local directory:

```
# ln -s ../lame-3.99.5/libmp3lame/libmp3lame.so ./libmp3lame.so.0
```

But "./" seems to be not in the shared library search path so ffmpeg doesn't find it.

I tried following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:./"
LIB_PATH="$LIB_PATH:./"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./"
./ffmpeg
```

But it still does not work.

I do not want to install the library as root (e.g. into /usr/lib) because I do not want to install anything without the official package manager + trusted Debian package sources.

So is there any way to tell ffmpeg to use the libmp3lame.so.0 in the "./" directory so I can use it without installing?

Comment: Have you tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/lame-3.99.5/libmp3lame/`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it now. It did not solve the problem :-/

Answer (score 1):

There is a debian multimedia repository, which has many of the '*unsupported*' multimedia applications and libraries.

For your /etc/apt/sources.list (better to put in a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d)

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ testing main non-free
deb-src http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ testing main non-free
```

Works well for me, check out the website (same address) for details on different debian versions.

I added those lines, plus some explanatory comments into a file, saved into **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/multimedia.list**, works very well.  There are restrictions on what the file can be named, see [**sources.list (5)**](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I already tried deb-multimedia.org at my testing machine. But I have 2 problems with it. (1) I did not find any GPG key which I could add to the trust chain, so aptitude did always bug me with a security alert when I wanted to install something. And (2) I am not sure if I should trust this repository since the server is a public webserver and should only contain stable software. I feel a bit uncomfortable with installing an "untrusted" repository to the package manager. (Or maybe I am just a bit paranoid ;-) )

Comment: From the front page of the website: 
The first package to install is **deb-multimedia-keyring**.
Since Squeeze you can install this package with apt-get but you need to presse Y when the package ask what to do and do not just press return.  I've been using it for quite a while, always been stable releases.  Public Webserver?  He owns the domain...
An new “apt-get update” is also necessary.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed the hint with the "deb-multimedia-keyring" package. I was thinking you have to enter the fingerprint manually with dpkg. Ok, problem #1 solved ;-) With "public webserver" I meant my box. Since I want to use ffmpeg on a webserver (as conversation tool) I want to be on the safe side and only install stable releases from official sources. And for my scenario it would be OK if I just have a self-compiled built running in the user's directory (... if ffmpeg could just find the library)